# is there a way to pause and resume html elements from loading in JavaScripts?

Tags: javascript, html

is there a way to pause and resume HTML elements from loading in JavaScripts? In another word, is the "window.stop()" method cancellable/reversible?

Comment: are you talking about specific elements that have not been loaded yet?

Comment: @dGRAMOP - thanks for leaving comments. Nope, I am looking for a way to stop loading all HTML elements and/or specific elements, make some api calls, then resume loading elements depending on the result of promise.

Comment: Why not just load your HTML without this stuff, then dynamically create it with JS depending on the result of your api calls?

Comment: Do your api calls return information you need, or do they change the state on the server?

Comment: @DrewKennedy - I don't have control over /access to the backend or whatever that is working, so by default everything is going to be loaded.

Comment: @NocNit - API will return information that I need for when deciding what to show and what not to show(in this test, the user name). This is, of course, having security concerns but it's out of my reach.

Comment: In that case I think @DrewKennedy has the right answer, let your page load without the optional stuff and, depending on the result of the API call (username), add the necessary elements with JS.

Comment: @NocNit - The only problem is that I have no control over what's to be loaded by default. So my idea was to pause the loading behavior, then let it resume loading. Everything will be loaded by default but I am trying to hide partial of the elements according to the result of API call.

Comment: @LeoL I get where you are coming from. How much control do you have? You can edit javascript on the page right?

Comment: Could you just hide the relevant elements with CSS, then unhide certain ones after the API returns?

Comment: @NocNIt - I don't have control at all, except adding a new script file to it.

Comment: @chazsolo - I am currently doing that in JavaScript, which will give me a flash before it disappears. So I am looking for other ways to make it happen more seamlessly, visually speaking.

Comment: @LeoL Based on what you've told me, I think it's best to use an overlay. You can use Javascript to place a `div` element on top of your page (which you can do with `z-index`) with a colored background. You can do your API calls and then remove the overlay. You could even put in a nice spinning progress indicator or something.

Comment: @NocNit - I see, you are thinking of putting something to cover it? That may be another good approach, thanks!